# Xcode Label of selected Cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

i want to start a timer label in a custom cell, when the button in the cell was pressed. How can i display that label in the selected cell? I used tag to connect the label to my table view.
Thanks

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString *CellIdentifier;

CellIdentifier = @"Cell01";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

// Configure the cell...
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Button
Button = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:104];
[Button addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

theLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:105];

return cell; }
```

And here is the button action

```
-(void)ButtonClicked:(id)sender {

UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
NSIndexPath *clickedButtonPath = [self.TableView indexPathForCell:clickedCell];
NSInteger ClickedRow = clickedButtonPath.row;
// In the clickedButtonPath, this allow us to find out the row that was selected by the user.

NSLog(@"%@",clickedCell);

switch(ClickedRow)
{
    case 1:
    {
        // first row
    }
        break;

    case 2:
    {
        // second row
    }
        break;
}}
```

Comment: Have you read Apple's documentations on TableViewControllers and TabeViewCells? All you need is explained there.

Comment: on the UITableView instance, reloadData or reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: should do what you need.  Trigger that when the data is updated.

Comment: Yeah i have read Apple´s documentations. But it isn´t helpful. I want to change the UILabel of the selected cell if the button of the cell pressed. And i can´t set outlets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first mistake is you are not created a custom cell, the cell you creating does´t have view 104 and 105. More in code:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// this 1.-
NSString *CellIdentifier;

 CellIdentifier = @"Cell01";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

 // Configure the cell...

 // Here you create a new UITableViewCell.


if (cell == nil)
 {
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }
 // this 2.
 // Button
 Button = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:104];

 // This is nil. You can add
 NSLog(@"See this button %@",[Button description]);
 // And see nil in the console.

 [Button addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonClicked:)      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 // The same thing this label
theLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:105];



return cell; }
```

If you are using Storyboards(or interface builder), in the cell in stroryboard be sure the reuseIdentifier is Cell01, and change al code between: this 1.- and this 2.- by:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell01" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

The last step will be: 
1.- In Storyboard or in code quit the default select behavior, in code you must add this just above
the cell created.

```
 cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

2.- Add didSelect and undo:

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UILabel *theLabel = (UILabel *)[selectedCell viewWithTag:105];
theLabel.text = @"New Selected text";
 }

 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
UILabel *theLabel = (UILabel *)[selectedCell viewWithTag:105];
theLabel.text = @"Non Selected text";

}
```

Comment: Thanks. But i want to know how to change a UILabel from the selected cell, when i pressed the button

Comment: the easy way is use the delegate methods of your tableView: (tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:. If you have connected well your cell in Storyboard and code, and adding a NSLog to UILabel this is created, let me know and I will write for you this method.

Comment: Yes i have already created the Label and connected it with the tag. Can you send me a example code? Thanks

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn´t work. It always selected the last cell :(

Comment: Can you update with your current code? The problem is no change the last cell only, the problem must be that the UILabel is the same in all cells, do you have any default text for no select ? , and you can see in all cells?.

Comment: Do you know how to range the selected field for a cell?

Comment: In general, to do things like that is better approach make a UITableViewCell subclass,  by example in your code you create a LeMyTableViewCell, (add new file LeMyTableViewCell.h and LeMyTableViewCell.m) and in stroyboard select the cell and connect with this custom cell, all you need to access (UIButton, UITextField...), you create as a property. 
By example myTextField is a property fon my custom cell, and in order to know in wich cell is one of my textField I can use its tag, in the cellForRow... I do:
cell.myTextField.tag = indexPath.row;
Well, Apple doc is great.

Comment: Ok i will use it in the future. Thanks :D